# asp.net update-database error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en visual studio creando mis modelos, mis controladores a partir de mi modelos y todo bien, el problema es que cometi un error al ponernle una propiedad que no queria al modelo y luego que quise cambiarla me sale este error en el update-database

Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'cargos' and 'Cargoes' can both contain instances of type 'pruebaSql.Models.Cargo'.

En la unica parte donde tengo algo que se llama Cargos es en el DbContext, el cual es este

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Data.Entity;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

  namespace pruebaSql.Models
 {
public class appDb : DbContext
{
    public appDb()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    DbSet<Empleado> empleados { get; set; }
    DbSet<Departamento> departamentos { get; set; }
    DbSet<Cargo> cargos { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<pruebaSql.Models.Empleado> Empleadoes { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<pruebaSql.Models.Departamento> Departamentoes { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<pruebaSql.Models.Cargo> Cargoes { get; set; }
}
 }
```

No entiendo el por que del error, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tienes datos repetidos en tu DbContext. Puedes borrar las ultimas 3 líneas ya que estas volviendo a definir los DbSet para Empleado, Departamento y Cargo:

```
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<pruebaSql.Models.Empleado> Empleadoes { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<pruebaSql.Models.Departamento> Departamentoes { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<pruebaSql.Models.Cargo> Cargoes { get; set; }
```

siempre que necesites cambiar propiedades de tu modelo por x motivo, recuerda que para ese tipo de casos están las migraciones. En el DbContext solo definimos las clases que queremos vallan a nuestra BD como tablas. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, al rato la implemento